# Why did Rey react that way towards BB8?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, star-wars, the-force-awakens

In *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* Rey saves BB8 from some thugs and just walks away from it, annoyed that it tried to follow her. BB8 chirps something (this whole scene not subtitled) that makes her answer with a disgusted "Nooo".

A few seconds later later, she allows him to follow her.

What's happening here? She saved the little guy and just sent it away, so why save it at all? It's clear that she doesn't make friends and [won't try to sell BB8](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142565/why-doesnt-rey-sell-bb8), so I'm confused.

BB8 needs to find people so it can carry on with its mission [as explained in this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112553/why-does-bb-8-follow-rey), but what's up with Rey in this scene? There's no subtitles to any of the alien dialogues.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [**Screenplay**](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Force-Awakens.html) helps here.*

<sup>*[See SF&F Valorum's Answer regarding why BB8 follows Rey](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112553/why-does-bb-8-follow-rey)</sup>

> She heads off again. Finally he BEEPS to her -- something SWEET this time. That **he is alone, scared, has no one else**.
>
> This makes her stop. She turns and looks at him. Not liking him. But a gesture of her head says, reluctantly, *"Come on."* BB-8 quickly moves to her. They head off together.
>
> REY (CONT'D) *In the morning, you go.*
>
> (HE BEEPS)
>
> *You're welcome.*

Since we've established that Rey can understand BB8 she can, apparently, tell that he's scared. **She feels sorry for him**...and allows him to tag along, at least for now.

Since we've established that [she won't sell him](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142565/why-doesnt-rey-sell-bb8) (as you stated), it seems that the sympathy grows into affection.

The question comes up, why save BB8 at all?

Again, the screenplay helps.

> Rey watches this **injustice** for a beat...

So she saves him...because he's a **person** not a thing to her. The "thug" wasn't planning on keeping BB8 around..

> REY (CONT'D) That's just Teedo. **Wants you for parts.** He has no respect for anyone.

Comment: But that's quite a weird interaction between them, why would she save BB8 in the first place? She can't have empathised with him before saving him, and why save a droid if she wasn't planning to sell or be friends with?

Comment: You can still empathise with someone you don't know. As for why she saved him, he's a **person** not a thing to her. The "thug" wasn't planning on keeping BB8 around... Reys says *"That's just Teedo. Wants you for parts. He has no respect for anyone."*.

Comment: I see, good points